# Installing Fedora 24 in dual boot mode not working

Tags: fedora, system-installation, dual-boot, uefi

I'm trying to install Fedora 24 side to side to Windows 8.1. I previously was running Debian 8 next to Windows and wanted to swap to Fedora. I'm trying to install from a USB live distro; some info:

- The ssd has two windows partitions and about 90GB of unallocated space.
- If I choose the automatic partition option, the installer complains that there is no free space available.
- If I partition the space myself, the installer complains about not having a `/boot/efi` partition available (even if I specifically allocate one in the installer).
- It's an ASUS motherboard and I've got fastboot disabled.
- I also deleted the PK keys to disable secure boot and choose `other OS` in the secure boot bios option.

Running `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` from the Fedora live stick gives the following output:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/sda: 488397168 sectors, 232.9 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 70D91666-A3FE-4C49-A75B-76546492EDF4
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 488397134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 190208301 sectors (90.7 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          206847   100.0 MiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   2          206848       297166847   141.6 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   3       297166848       298190847   500.0 MiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
```

Partition number 3 was an attempt to create a NFTS partition from Win 8 to use for `/boot/efi` which wasn't successful and didn't make any difference....

Any idea what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know why it seems much easier to [find an answer](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/67667/hdd-partitioning-error-during-fedora-21-installation/) once you wrote down the question.... (thanks Ahmad)

I stubbornly booted the USB by selecting the option with the 'UEFI' prefix. Choosing the option without it fixed my issue...